# How can I use list comprehension for the list unique?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I use list comprehension for the list unique?

```
original_list = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5, 4], [0, 5, 4, 1], [3, 7, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2]]
new_list = [elements for items in original_list for elements in items]
unique = []
for item in new_list:
    if item not in unique:
        unique.append(item)
print(unique)
```

Comment: @a121 For large lists, this implementation will be horribly inefficient.  The correct way to do this is with a set comprehension.

Comment: You almost have the answer. You need to convert the list comprehension to a set and back to a list. `new_list = list({elements for items in original_list for elements in items})
` will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use set comprehension:

```
uniques = {elements for items in original_list for elements in items}
```

will give you the set

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
```

You can convert it to a `list` if you want

```
uniques = list(uniques)
```